# dependent samples, binary data, multiple tests?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binary-data, mcnemar-test

In each of my five experiments I run several trials which give me a certain success rate (e.g. 10 successful trials out of 30 tested), then a drug is applied and the same trials are run to give a success rate for the second condition (e.g. 1/30). So my samples are dependent, and the success rates are not normally distributed. I want to know if the drug changes the success rate - what test should I use? I think the appropriate would be something like multiple McNemar-Test?